# Why is Mr Walsh responsible for the finances of the Goon Docks

Tags: the-goonies

> Data:(Changing the subject) Hey, any of you guys ever hear of Detroit?
>
> Mikey: No.
>
> Mouth: Soitenly. That's where Motown started. It's also got the highest murder rate in the country.
>
> Data: Well let me tell you what. That's where we're moving when we lose our house tomorrow.
>
> Mikey: You shut up about that stuff. It'll never happen. My dad'll fix it.
>
> Brand: Yeah, sure he will. If he gets his next four hundred paycheques by tomorrow afternoon.
>
> Mikey: That's wrong Brand. It won't happen!

When the subject of saving the Goon Docks comes up, Mikey and Brand imply that the financial problems hinge on Mr Walsh being unable to pay bills/enough money to keep Troy's father from foreclosing.

Why is Mr Walsh the only one responsible when we know that there are other families living there who should be at least partly responsible for the financial security of the area. Why would Data's family be affected by the Walsh's inability to pay their own bills?

Comment: Are you sure that is really implied here? Sounds to me like the line is simply a comeback to “My dad will fix it.“ i.e. Mikey is trusting that his father will somehow find a solution some way (because, you know, he is his father and awesome) and Brand tries to convince him how unrealistic that is.

Comment: @atticae When it comes time to sign the papers, Mr Walsh is the only one told to come over to sign. If all the others had already signed, then their signatures would have already been binding despite him tearing up his own papers. If the others had not signed yet, it seems odd that no one else was told to come over to sign next.

Answer (score 1):

"Common, Walsh, there's fifty more house to tear down **after** yours!" emphasis Troy's.

The Walsh'es and their neighbors face [foreclosure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goonies) (for some legally questionable reason) on their homes from the expanding Astoria Country Club. Presumably the Walsh family lives between the country club and everyone else.

However, it seems unreasonable that the 50 families in the area all can't pay their mortgage and taxes and are facing foreclosure. Rather, they have been made offers they can not refuse and the Walsh'es are the one family thought even remotely capable of refusing the offer to be bought out. Everyone probably hates Mr. Walsh now. Data's family would not be able to afford/need moving to Detroit. Data is angry just like the rest of the kids because they're all going to move away from each other. The paper at the end is a 'final notice' not a 'notice of foreclosure'. Besides, you *get* foreclosed on, you don't sign for it.

Comment: Do you remember the housing bubble pop a few years ago? There have been plenty of other bubbles over the years to which this could have been related. There was also a savings and loan debacle in the 80s that hurt many people, to which this could have been a reference. There were other movies from the same era with similar themes, like batteries not included

Comment: Good insight with the S and L debacle. I'll have to research the intricacies of foreclosure further. And watch batteries not included again, too! @atk

Comment: Only the government has the power of imminent domain. The question might then be how far Troy's dad's gilded hands reach into the pockets of the local politicians. The Blues Brothers had a similar plot device in that churches don't have to pay taxes.